# Generating Dynamic URL and setting form method to Post

Tags: javascript, forms

I am generating a URL based off of user input, and the html and java script is in the same file, java script functions are in the script tag,

```
<form name="generate" action="javascript:openUrl" method="post" onSubmit="return createUrl()">
  <table>
    <tr><td>Select Instance :</td>
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Email : </td><td><input type="text" style="width:300px;" name="email" ng-model="email" class="ticker-textbox" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Expiration Date: </td><td><input type="text" style="width:150px;" name="expiryDate" class="ticker-textbox" />mm/dd/yyyy</td></tr>
    <tr><td style="padding-bottom: 10px;">First Name : </td><td><input type="text" style="width:300px;" name="firstName" class="ticker-textbox" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Last Name : </td><td><input type="text" style="width:300px;" name="lastName" class="ticker-textbox" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Generated URL :</td><td><input disabled type="text" style="width:800px;" name="genURL" class="ticker-textbox" /></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" name="button" value="Generate URL" onclick="createUrl()"/></td>
      <td><input type="button" name="open" value="Open URL" onclick="openUrl()"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I cannot get the method to be set to POST, still no matter what, it sets the method to GET.

I have tried using jquery for setting $.post in the create URL function, but it says that $ is not recognized.

FUNCTIONS:

```
 var createUrl = function () {

             var url = document.generate.instance.value + '/user/remoteLogin.html?clientName=' + cn;

             if (hasText(document.generate.expiryDate.value)) {
               var expiryDate = urlEncode(document.generate.expiryDate.value);
               url += ('&expirationDate=' + expiryDate);
               window.key = window.key.substring(0, window.key.length - document.generate.expiryDate.value.length)
               window.key += document.generate.expiryDate.value;
             }

             var decodedKey = decodeBase64(window.key);
             if (hasText(document.generate.email.value)) {
               var em = urlEncode(encrypt(decodedKey, document.generate.email.value));
               em = em.trim();
               url += ('&em=' + em);

             }

             if (hasText(document.generate.firstName.value)) {
               var fn = urlEncode(encrypt(decodedKey, document.generate.firstName.value));
               url += ('&fn=' + fn);
             }

             if (hasText(document.generate.lastName.value)) {
               var ln = urlEncode(encrypt(decodedKey, document.generate.lastName.value));
               url += ('&ln=' + ln);
             }

             document.generate.genURL.value = url;

             return true;
           }

         }
         var openUrl = function () {

             location.href = document.generate.genURL.value;

             return false;
           }
         }
```

Comment: That likely means you didn't include jQuery in your header tag. You can grab jQuery from here https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js. Either that or you're running jQuery code before jQuery loads.

Comment: "$ is not recognized" if you are getting this then you didn't include jQuery in your page. But it may not be necessary. You need to show us the code in "openUrl". also it maybe needs to be `javascript:openUrl()` with the brackets. support for this syntax is not universal though, you may want to handle the submit event of the form instead.

Comment: Added code for the two functions

Comment: location.href can only do a GET. your approach is all wrong. why on earth are you letting the user set the URL anyway?